How to remove affiliation superscript in elsarticle class for single author?
I'm using the elsarticle class from Elsevier for my paper as follows:
\documentclass[preprint,3p,number]{elsarticle}
\title{Title}

\author[1]{My Name}%\corref{cor1}}
\ead{mail@xmail.com}
 
 \affiliation[1]{
                organization={My University},
                country={USA}
                }

In the generated PDF, small superscripts "a" appear next to the name and affiliation as follows:

Since I am the only author, I don't need these superscript indicators. How can I remove the "a" and just show the name and affiliation without any numbering or superscript?

The [1] is optional. Guess what happens if it is not there....
